# pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module doesn't work on server [PYTHON]

Tags: python, winapi

I wrote a program that uses win32 library. 
To be more specific - this program uses `win32.client` package, When I turn on the script on the computer, everything works. the problem appears when trying to write `cgi` which uses the code of my program.

What may causes this problem? 
why the server program can not download the needed resource?

When trying to find the cause, I cameacross on the file `pythoncom.py`

Code below:

```
import pywintypes
pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module__("pythoncom", globals())
```

P.S. I copied the folder from the library to the win32 directory ktrym project is located

Comment: Show the source code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: #!/Python27/python <br>
import cgi, cgitb <br>


cgitb.enable()  #for debugging <br/>

from QCAPI.QCTestSetReport import QCTestSetReport
from win32com.client import Dispatch    #This line causes problem. Here is debugging result:<br/> 1.C:\xampp\cgi-bin\example.py in ()<br/>   2.C:\xampp\cgi-bin\win32com\client\__init__.py in () <br/>  3.  C:\xampp\cgi-bin\win32com\client\dynamic.py in () <br/>  4. C:\xampp\cgi-bin\win32com\client\build.py in ()

Comment: When I try import win32com.client , my script doesn't work. Rest of my code is not important. Why I can't use windows utilities?

Comment: Please put the code you your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved! unnecessarily I copied folder with library win32 to fiolder with my project, and pythons interpreter had a problem with localization this library.